# Controlled Integration of Changes with Continuous Integration

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, visual-sourcesafe, release-management

I have a NSIS installer that we previously built using nAnt scripts that copy some files around and run makensis.exe via a exec task to build the installer exe.  After the nant script completes, I have the compelte structure for our CD and also our download.

I was just doing a get from sourcesafe onto an unused desktop and using it as a build box, compiling there.  Sometimes we would have a couple of files checked in that fix something critical.  In those cases I would go to the build box, and very selectively get only those files, to avoid getting other changed files that we aren't ready to release yet.  Basically I am able to allow development to continue and selectively include certain changed files into the installer for release.

Now we no longer have a free box, and need to build from our server.  So I am setting up CI Factory so that the developer can kick the build off without remoting into the server.  The one issue I am struggling with, is the best way to continue to allow this selective change control to occur.  The default concept of CI that CI Factory implements is fine for internal development "head".  However, I also want to setup a CCNet project that is run only on demand via a Force Build for this "public release" type of build.

This is what I've brain stormed so far, without being sure how well this will work, if at all(still figuring out what CCNet and CI Factory are all about).  The "public release" CCNet project config/build would be setup such that it would **not** get latest.  Modifications would **not** trigger a build.  Since the other CCNet project that is using the default CI methodology(we'll call it the "CI project") of getting latest when changes are detected, then these two projects can't share the same working directory.  So the "public release" would need a different working copy, so that its files won't get updated when the CI project's build is triggered.  The developer would need to remote into the server, one VSS, selectively do a get into the "public release"'s working copy, and then force a build through CI Factory.

The disadvantage's I see with this is
1) Having to remote in to selectively do gets.
2) I have no idea how to allow a single CI Factory project to have two different working copies of the Product folder, so that each project configuration block has it's own.
3) I'm afraid of what kind of strangeness this might cause.  I'm not quite sure yet how to specify a source control block in CCNet project config block, but prevent it from doing a get latest when it builds.  I'm still gradually figuring out what things are in scripts and can be easily taken out without breaking other things, versus what is not meant to be mucked around with and/or is not configurable.

I would really like to hear about how others deal with this issue of selectively releasing changes, if you have a similar situation.  I am constrained to VSS, so my immediate need is to solve this with that in mind, but at the same time I'd be interested in hearing how you manage this with other source control systems.  I guess you would probably have a branch that is your latest developments branch, and then merge changes into the trunk whenever you want to release them?  I really don't trust VSS for branching/merging, and I think the branching concepts might be a little too much overhead and learning curve for this shop.  Like I said though, stories with other source control systems would be useful future knowledge for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a branching structure in your repository to facilitate this.  Something like the release branch method.  Only select individuals can commit to this branch (or have a release/stable for that).  Set up your manual CI launches to pull from the release branch as release nightly promote to milestone or final from there.  I don't like the idea of manually modifying things on your build machine.  Set up the changes in version control, in a safe place to prepare your release and let CI build from there, but manually triggered.

Check out these [branching patterns](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/acme/branching/). I suggested C3, codeline-per-release, often called release branching.

Heres an [article](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe/branch-in-sourcesafe-vss.html) on VSS branching that includes a link to merging.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404948/practical-way-to-commit-changes-in-source-control-to-multiple-branches) looks similar.

Maybe you could move to another source control system with better support for this kind of thing.  Any suggestions from MS people out there?

Comment: Thanks.  So, with VSS would your technique be to have a working copy of both the "head" and the "public release", and selectively copying files from my head working copy to the public release working copy and checking them in?  I have never used merge in VSS, not sure if it's any good.

Comment: I haven't used vss in a while, but yes, my suggestion would likely require the ability merge changes from the trunk to the release as they became available, and to backport changes from the release to the trunk if necessary.